# Two way binding of ngModel between components with validation

Tags: angular, validation

I am trying to bind a value from parent component to child component so its reusable.

**parent-component.ts**

```
 profile:any = {name:"", mobile:""}
```

**Parent-component.html**

```
<app-profile-name label="Name" [(name)]="profile.name"></app-profile-name>
```

**child component.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="name" appUppercase
     required minlength="3" maxlength="50" pattern="[a-zA-Z\s\.]*" #nameInput="ngModel" (keyup)="onKeyup($event)">
    <div *ngIf="nameInput.invalid && (nameInput.dirty || nameInput.touched)" class="form-control-text text-danger animated fadeIn">
      <small *ngIf="nameInput.errors.required" class="d-block">Name is required</small>
      <small *ngIf="nameInput.errors.pattern" class="d-block">Alphabets dot and space is only allowed</small>
      <small *ngIf="nameInput.errors.minlength" class="d-block">Name should be minimum 3 characters</small>
      <small *ngIf="nameInput.errors.maxlength" class="d-block">Name should be maximum 3 characters</small>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Child component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, DoCheck, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile-name',
  templateUrl: './profile-name.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile-name.component.css']
})
export class ProfileNameComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {

  @Input() name: String;
  @Output() nameChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @ViewChild('nameInput') nameInput:any;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  ngDoCheck() {
    setTimeout(()=>{      
      this.nameChange.next(this.name);
    });

  }

}
```

This code works absolutely fine.

Here are the test input cases where validation fails but still i could see the data binded

1. A -> Does not match the requirement min length 3. So i am getting an error message. But the parent profile.name is binded with input A

So i did a modification in the code as

```
ngDoCheck() {
    setTimeout(()=>{      
      if(this.nameInput.invalid){ // added this if condition
        this.nameChange.next("")
        return;
      }
      this.nameChange.next(this.name);
    });

  }
```

Here are the following cases

Now if i press A and since the validation min length 3 is not met, i am getting empty profile.name

If i enter A1ASDF, since the validation is failed, i am  getting empty profile.name.

Now if i enter ALAKS, now i have cleared the validation and so i get value in my profile.name

Follwing to it if i enter number 1, which will set ALAKS1 it fails the validation. So my profile.name goes to "" simultaneously, this.name also disappears and i get an empty input box.

The question is how can i restore the input box value and get only the valid input value in my parent component.

Hope i made the question clear.

**Working Answer**
Special thanks to @Andiry.

As i ended up in infinity loop, i took the logic of @Andiry into blur and its working fine now.

Here is the updated code

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="name" appUppercase
     required minlength="3" maxlength="50" pattern="[a-zA-Z\s\.]*" #nameInput="ngModel" (blur)="onInputBlur()">
```

profile-name.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile-name',
  templateUrl: './profile-name.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile-name.component.css']
})
export class ProfileNameComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() name:string;
  @Output() nameChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @ViewChild('nameInput') nameInput:any;

  constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    onInputBlur(){
      let name = this.name;
        this.nameChange.emit(this.nameInput.invalid ? '' : this.name);
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.name = name;
      });
    }

}
```

Comment: please consider using `ngDoCheck` also you are using `setTimeout` inside it. This hook will be fired 20 times for a mouse move

Comment: It was an prescribed answer in stackoverflow. Yes. It filled my console and is there any other suggestive code method as i will be using 10-15 fields which are reusable in 5-6 pages

Comment: i m sorry i didnt get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to rewrite your child component to something like:

```
export class ProfileNameComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {
  nameValue: string;
  lastIsInvalid: boolean = true;

  @Input() get name() {
    return this.nameValue;
  }
  @Output() nameChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  set name(val) {
    let name = val;
    setTimeout(_ => {
      this.nameValue = val;
      this.nameChange.emit(this.nameInput.invalid ? '' : this.nameValue);
      if (this.lastIsInvalid !== this.nameInput.invalid) {
        setTimeout(_ => this.name = name);
      }
      this.lastIsInvalid = this.nameInput.invalid;
    });
  }

  @ViewChild('nameInput') nameInput:any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

STACKBLITZ: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-emq3ef?file=app%2Fprofile-name%2Fprofile-name.component.ts

Comment: It binds whatever i typein. I want the value to be binded only if there its valid. If invalid, the parent variable should be empty. But child variable to have its value.

Comment: I added `lastIsInvalid` flag, please see my updated answer. I also created a STACKBLITZ (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-emq3ef?file=app%2Fprofile-name%2Fprofile-name.component.ts), if your issue persists, update my stackblitz and I will try to help

Comment: Hi..Thanks for your effort and this is what i exactly wanted. I copied and pasted your code into my project files and I am ending up in infinite loop into my project. I didnt change anything and i cross referred with stackblitz code... Can u guide me why i am endingup with infinite loop. https://www.dropbox.com/s/lv0j8xemnrs9326/2017-12-11_18h10_58.mp4?dl=0

Comment: Kindly give me some information about the use of _ in setTimeout  setTimeout(_

Comment: I usually use underscore (_) as mandatory argument name which will not be used anywhere in its function block. In this particular example of `setTimeout` it is just replacing `() => ....` syntax.